# How to derive this HJB equation?

Tags: brownian-motion, stochastic-control

I'm reading the paper by J.Gatheral and A.Schied (2012) - "[Optimal Trade Execution under
Geometric Brownian Motion in the Almgren and Chriss Framework](https://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=1654151)".

On page 6, the authors provide a value function, which maps initial conditions with minimal cost value ($T$ - Time remaining to expire position, $X$ - value of position, $S_0$ - asset price at first moment of time). The function can be expressed as:
$$
C(T,X,S_0) = \inf_{v \in V(T,X)}\mathbb{E}\left[\int_0^Tv^2_tdt + \lambda \int_0^Tx_t^v S_tdt \right]
$$

I'm struggling with deriving the HJB equation for this case, which has the form:
$$
C_T = \frac{1}{2}\sigma^2S^2C_{SS} + \lambda SX + \inf_{v \in \mathbb{R}}\left(v^2 - vC_x\right)
$$
It is assumed that the asset price $S$ follows a geometrical Brownian motion with no drift, $dS_t = \sigma S_t dt$. I'm familiar with the Bellman principle, but it still seems unobvious to me.